# How to create a dictionary with no duplicating keys from two pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Say that I have a data frame `df` that looks like the following:

```
    A     B
0  key1   value1
1  key2   value2
2  key2   value3
3  key3   value4
4  key3   value5
```

How can I transform it into a dictionary `dic` that looks like this in the most time efficient way:

```
{key1: [value1], 
key2: [value2, value3], 
key3: [value4, value5]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` + `agg(list)` + `to_dict`:

```
out = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'key1': ['value1'],
 'key2': ['value2', 'value3'],
 'key3': ['value4', 'value5']}
```